# Bootstrap PHP Form Post method not working

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a register email page, which uses referral id, but if no user doesn't get referred by anyone, then by a redirect, I use default af id = 1 
with following code::

```
if ( !isset( $_GET['af'] ) && empty( $_GET['af'] ) ){
header('Location: register-email.php?af=1');exit();
}
```

Next Here is the form code:

```html
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" name="register_email" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">          
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group"> 
                 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">  
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="somecode"></div>
                     </div></div>
                     <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="register-email">Register Email</button>
                     </div></div>
        </form>
```

Here is the background PHP part:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],$_GET['af'])) {
$test="OK";
 }
```

It never prints "OK", I tested the GET part its working fine not empty or null value. **But email & g recaptcha part is null**. I am not sure why. Previously it used to work without bootstrap integration.

**Note**: I didn't use echo $test = OK because I am printing this on other pages with echo statement, whole process includes two files,

- register-email.php ( Here I am using the `echo $test;`)
- register-email.inc.php (which includes the isset POST sections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by myself after lots of debugging. The form was not working because of the redirect. So remove the code of redirect, in fact, use another type of safe coding in order to check if GET is variable is empty or not internally.

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
   if ( !isset( $_GET['af'] ) || empty( $_GET['af'] ) ){
      $af_code = 1;
     }  
      else {
          $af_code = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'af',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
           }
 }
```

Now its working safe & sound

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo $test. You just have stored it, you didn't printed it. And your condition is not even in right syntax.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question, I printing echo $test on another page. that's why on include file I didn't add echo.

Comment: I see. By the way, this line if (isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],$_GET['af'])) is not appropriate one. Try using this if (isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) AND isset($_GET['af']))

Comment: But $_POST['email'], $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] and $_GET['af'] is not empty, right?

Comment: isset determines if a variable is set and is not NULL. If $test is not printing OK that means its null.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes here. You cannot mix `$_GET` and `$_POST`, in this case, it must be all `$_POST`. When testing `isset()`, you cannot just use commas. How about the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) AND isset($_GET['af'])) {
 $test="OK";
 }
```

If the above code does not work, check this out.

```
if(!isset($_POST['email']) echo "Email not set";
if(!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) echo "Recaptcha not set";
if(!isset($_POST['af']) echo "AF not set";
```

Now you can see if any of them is not set. Do keep in mind, for `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` to have a value, a user must correctly answer the  **reCaptcha** image test (Human test), and **reCaptcha** must be correctly implemented.

Comment: Hi I applied your coding, but still not working. its not printing Ok.

Comment: I just updated the answer, check that out. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok I am checking individually, Coming back with the results. But your answer has syntax mistakes, you are missing one ")" for each 3 lines.

Comment: Done debugging, just like from the beginning I am mentioning, that it's only setting up the af code but rest of the email, & g captcha is not getting set up. I do type the email, solve the gcaptcha then hit the submit button correctly but nothing happens. email & gcaptcha is null.

Answer (score 0):

form action remove and change submit button name register_email. after add this php code. 
if(isset($_POST['register_email'])){header('Location: register-email.php?af=1');exit();}

Comment: removing form action can cause XSL attack. submit button name is already named as register_email. Not sure what is the logic for if(isset($_POST['register_email'])){header('Location: register-email.php?af=1');exit();}